# shape must be rank 4 but is rank 5 for max pool layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-processing, conv-neural-network

Hi I want to build a CNN Model for RGB images of 32x32x3
But the max pooling returns error saying:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "max_pooling2d_11" (type MaxPooling2D).

Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 5 for '{{node max_pooling2d_11/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]](max_pooling2d_11/MaxPool/input)' with input shapes: [1,?,32,32,16].

Call arguments received by layer "max_pooling2d_11" (type MaxPooling2D):
  • inputs=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 32, 32, 16), dtype=float32)',)
```

Here is the layers:

```py
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
Z = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding="same", activation="relu")(inputs),
Z = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(Z)
```

EDIT: Additional question:

Hi, I want to make a net that output an image of 32x32, but it gives some error. Here is the code:

```
codings_size=10
decoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[codings_size])

x=tf.keras.layers.Dense(3 * 3 * 16)(decoder_inputs)
x=tf.keras.layers.Reshape((3, 3, 16))(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, strides=2, activation="relu")(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, 3, strides=2, padding="same",
                              activation="relu")(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, strides=2, padding="same")(x)
outputs=tf.keras.layers.Reshape([32, 32])(x)

variational_decoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[decoder_inputs], outputs=[outputs])
```

Here is the error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "reshape_13" (type Reshape).

total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [28, 28, 1], output_shape = [32, 32]

Call arguments received by layer "reshape_13" (type Reshape):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: This error does not make any sense, do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: it has to do with the RGB images having 3 channels instead of 1. there is a solution on the internet to use `tf.reduce_max` instead (`Z=tf.compat.v1.reduce_max(Z,reduction_indices=[],keep_dims=True)`

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with anything, see the (correct) answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is you added additional comma, just delete it.

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
Z = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding="same", activation="relu")(inputs)
Z = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(Z)
```

For your new question you can do this before reshaping to 32,32:

```
...
x=tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, strides=2, activation="relu")(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, 3, strides=2,
                              activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, strides=2, padding="same")(x)
...
```

Comment: this solves the issue, now I add new model and have new error. can you please see the additional question?